# NUXT3 NuxtLink redirecting to wrong url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3, nuxt-link

I'm using NUXT3
When the URL is localhost:3000/Eventik/events and I click on a link

```
 <NuxtLink class="list-group-item" :to="/events/edit/${event.eventId}">{{ $t('edit') }}</NuxtLink>
```

inside the page,

> it works correctly and goes to the address localhost:3000/Eventik/events/edit/1.

However, when the URL is localhost:3000/Eventik/events/ and I click on the same link, it takes me to the wrong URL localhost:3000/Eventik/events/events/edit/1.

I tried

```
 <NuxtLink class="list-group-item" :to="edit/${event.eventId}">{{ $t('edit') }}</NuxtLink>
```

when the URL is localhost:3000/Eventik/events
the result -> localhost:3000/Eventik/edit/1 and it's not correct.

and  when the URL islocalhost:3000/Eventik/events or localhost:3000/Eventik/events/
with

```
 <NuxtLink class="list-group-item" :to="/edit/${event.eventId}">{{ $t('edit') }}</NuxtLink>
```

-> localhost:3000/edit/1

Comment: If possible, provide us a production link. In your case, it is harder for us to debug your issue. You can use stackblitz or codesanbox

Comment: @ReaganM 
I solve it by $route.path but I don't think if it's a good practices

<NuxtLink class="list-group-item" :to="`${$route.path[$route.path.length-1]==='/'?'':$route.path+'/'}edit/${event.eventId}`">{{ $t('edit') }}</NuxtLink>